# considering using spring social project

Tags: oauth, spring-social

In my application scope i need to implement daemons which collect users data from social networks...
the thing is that i don't need the full flow as described in the spring social project overview my assumption is that i already have the users OAuth token for each specific service provider lets assume that it can be fetched from my DB..

my question is where and how i intercept the common flow ( which is starting at get the OAuth token and save it using repository connection) and what are the minimal dependencies that i need for my implementation?

Thanks
Assaf

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this over in the Spring Social forums (http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124064-Using-Spring-Social-Project), but in case you didn't see it there...

The connection flow is useful for the common case where the app does not yet have the access token and needs to engage the user to obtain it. But if you already have it, then you can skip all of that and go straight to constructing the API bindings for yourself.

For example, if you already have a user's access token for Facebook, you'll just need to use it when constructing a FacebookTemplate:

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
```

Is that what you were looking for?